# Como navegar a otra pantalla correctamente con flutter, InkWell

Tags: flutter

Estoy con una App que contiene un SplashScreen, una pantalla Home, y otra con detalles.

Al momento de navegar desde la Home a la detalles, funciona perfectamente, pero cuando vuelvo para atrás, se queda en la SplashScreen.

El "botón" que estoy utilizando es un InkWell y en el método Ontap tengo el siguiente código:

onTap: () { Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => detalles()),
        ); }

Yo lo que quiero, es que cuando este navegando en la pantalla detalles, y presione el botón "atrás" de Android, vuelva a la Home.

Codigo del Splash:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
         home:Scaffold(
       body: HomePageBody(),
    )
    );
  }
}

class HomePageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageBodyState createState() => new _HomePageBodyState();
}


class _HomePageBodyState extends State<HomePageBody> {

  @override
  void initState() {          //SPLASH SCREEN
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(
        Duration (seconds: 3),
    () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ),
          );
    }
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    //PLASH SCREEN
    return new Scaffold(
      //appBar: new AppBar(),

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          new Container(
            height: 100.0,
          ),
          new Text(
              "¡Bienvenidos a Carhue!",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Tema.Colors.appBarGradientEnd,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              letterSpacing: 0.8,
              fontSize: 20.0,

            ),
          ),
          new Container(
           height: 120.0,
          ),
          new Image.asset(
          'fotos/fondo.jpg',
          width: 600.0,
          height: 240.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

        ),

      ],

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Codigo del Home:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Bienvenidos!',
        home:Scaffold(
          body: Home(),
        )
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home createState() => new _Home();
}


class _Home extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //color: Colors.yellow

    ),
    ),
    GradientAppBar("¡Vivi Carhue!"),
    menubotones(),

    ],
    )
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código que usas para llamar del Splash al Home ?

Comment: @diegoveloper ¿Como no?, ya edite la publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el HomePageBody en lugar de

```
   Navigator.push
```

Usa

```
   Navigator.replace
```